# Text & Spaces based table convert into array

Tags: python

What is the best way to convert text and spaces based table to convert into an array?

I am getting below output from one of the hardware readers.
I need to parse and get values for each cell.

```
TANK  PRODUCT               GALLONS  INCHES   WATER  DEG F   ULLAGE

  1   REGULAR UNLEADED  87    56987   75.77     0.0   83.3     4785
  2   18                       4578   86.08           83.6     1661
  3   SAMPLE                   1234   77.94     0.0   86.4     2140
```

Two Test Cases

- When Product column as space example "12 Data"
- When Product column as two space example "REGULAR UNLEADED  87"
- When any cell is blank.

Comment: What are your constraints? I can think of a string-function based solution or I could recommend pandas, but which fits better depends on what you are looking for. This includes what you want to do with the table. Also, you tagged this question 'explode'. If that is supposed to mean that you are looking for functionality like the PHP function, please say so in the question text. It's probably best to remove the tag, unless actually using PHP is an option for you.

Comment: Sorry, @JannPoppinga for the confusion. I removed that tag. I was looking for something like a similar method explodes in PHP. but for an answer with the help of Szymon.

Comment: https://www.jafsoft.com/asctotab/ I haven't tried it, but it looks promising.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Actually windows antivirus blocking that file to run. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have spaces in the cells and  your data, you need a bit RegExp magic:

```
import re

s = """
TANK  PRODUCT               GALLONS  INCHES   WATER  DEG F   ULLAGE

  1   12 Data                 56987   75.77     0.0   83.3     4785
  2   18                       4578   86.08     0.0   83.6     1661
  3   SAMPLE                   1234   77.94     0.0   86.4     2140
"""

s = re.sub('^\n', '', s)     # remove empty line a the start of 's'
s = re.sub('\n+ +', '\n', s) # remove spaces at the start of lines and empty lines
s = re.sub('\s +', '\t', s)  # replace two or more spaces with tab

table = [row.split('\t') for row in s.splitlines()]

print(table)
```

Output:

```
[
    ['TANK', 'PRODUCT', 'GALLONS', 'INCHES', 'WATER', 'DEG F', 'ULLAGE'], 
    ['1', '12 Data', '56987', '75.77', '0.0', '83.3', '4785'], 
    ['2', '18', '4578', '86.08', '0.0', '83.6', '1661'], 
    ['3', 'SAMPLE', '1234', '77.94', '0.0', '86.4', '2140']
]
```

But it works only if you have at least 2 spaces outside the cells and use single spaces inside the cells.

---

Short variant (the same output):

```
import re

s = """
TANK  PRODUCT               GALLONS  INCHES   WATER  DEG F   ULLAGE

  1   12 Data                 56987   75.77     0.0   83.3     4785
  2   18                       4578   86.08     0.0   83.6     1661
  3   SAMPLE                   1234   77.94     0.0   86.4     2140
"""

s = re.sub('  +', '\t', s)   # replace two or more spaces with tab

table = [row.strip().split('\t') for row in s.splitlines() if len(row) > 1]

print(table)
```

---

Expanded version. It can handle the empty cells:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

s = """
TANK  PRODUCT               GALLONS  INCHES   WATER  DEG F   ULLAGE

  1   REGULAR UNLEADED 87     56987   75.77     0.0   83.3     4785
  2   18                       4578   86.08           83.6     1661
  3   SAMPLE                   1234   77.94     0.0   86.4     2140
"""

lines = s.splitlines()                  # split the data by lines
lines = [l for l in lines if len(l)>0]  # remove empty lines

# function takes a line
# and returns a list of separators (positions of left edges of the cells)
def get_separators(line):
    separators = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(line)-1:
        i += 1
        if line[i] == " ": continue      # skip all spaces
        while i < len(line)-2:
            i += 1
            if line[i] != " ": continue  # then skip all non spaces
            if line[i+1] == " ":         # if there are two spaces
                separators.append(i)     # add the position to the separators
                break
    separators.append(len(line))         # add a separator at the end
    return separators

# get separators from the first line
separators = get_separators(lines[0])

# go through all lines and adjust positions of separators
for line in lines:
    separators_cur_line = get_separators(line)
    if len(separators) != len(separators_cur_line): continue
    for i, sep in enumerate(separators_cur_line):
        if sep > separators[i]:
            separators[i] = sep

# function takes a line and a list of separators
# and returns a list of cells (the line divided by the separators)
def get_cells(line, separators):
    res=[]
    start = 0
    for end in separators:
        cell = line[start:end].strip()
        start = end
        res.append(cell)
    return res

# get cells from all lines
data = [get_cells(line, separators) for line in lines]

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[
   ['TANK', 'PRODUCT', 'GALLONS', 'INCHES', 'WATER', 'DEG F', 'ULLAGE'],
   ['1', 'REGULAR UNLEADED 87', '56987', '75.77', '0.0', '83.3', '4785'],
   ['2', '18', '4578', '86.08', '', '83.6', '1661'],
   ['3', 'SAMPLE', '1234', '77.94', '0.0', '86.4', '2140']
]
```

Limitations:

- Only single spaces allowed inside cells.
- At least two spaces should be between columns and cells.
- Cell can contain only one line.

Comment: Looks much better than the previous solution. Works great.
I found one more test case when one cell is blank and needs to keep in an array as blank. Otherwise, it will go with the wrong column.

Comment: I think empty cells can be handle If columns has a fixed predicable width (based on a first line of a table, for example). But the algorithm will be much more complicated. Are you sure you can't change the empty data with some placeholder symbols like '--' or something? It would be way easer, I think.

Comment: And I'm quite sure any spreadsheet app (Excel, Google Spreadsheet, Libre Calc, etc) can open such txt data and parse it into common csv format or xls with no sweat. Did you consider such solution? Probably even VS Code has some extension for this task.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I can't change that. It's veeder root device and I can read that output via telnet only. And no control over that hardware at all.
Temp: I did the below code. It mashed up at header value I think cell having 3 or more space.

result = re.sub('   +', '\t', result)           # replace three or more spaces with tab
result = [row.strip().split('\t') for row in result.splitlines() if len(row) > 1]

Comment: I've made the expanded version which able to handle the empty cells. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try leveraging `str.splitlines()` and `str.split()` methods, eg.:

```
s = """
TANK  PRODUCT               GALLONS  INCHES   WATER  DEG F   ULLAGE

  1   12                      56987   75.77     0.0   83.3     4785
  2   18                       4578   86.08     0.0   83.6     1661
  3   SAMPLE                   1234   77.94     0.0   86.4     2140
"""
result = []
for row in s.splitlines():
    result.append(row.split())
```

alternatively, using list comprehension:

```
result = [row.split() for row in s.splitlines()]
```

Comment: small issue when data is "12 Data" in the Product column with space.
Can you please help with that one?

Comment: sorry just noticed someone already answered this but I'll post it here as well for the record - use `row.split('\t')` to split rows on tabs instead of whitespace characters